# Diffusion equation issue

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

I need help, I’m stuck on this problem. Below is my progress.

[image: The question]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- $\ds{\on{u}_{x}\pars{x,t} =
  -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\on{a}_{n}\pars{t}\,n\sin\pars{nx}}$ already satisfies
  $\ds{\on{u}_{x}\pars{0,t} = \on{u}_{x}\pars{\pi,t} = 0}$. Note that
  \begin{equation}
  \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\pars{mx}\cos\pars{nx}\,\dd x =
  {\pi \over 2}\,\delta_{mn}\label{1}\tag{1}
  \end{equation}
- $\ds{\on{u}\pars{x,t} =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\on{a}_{n}\pars{t}\cos\pars{nx} + \on{f}\pars{t}}$ which must satisfies the above partial differential equation. Namely,
  \begin{align}
  &\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dot{\on{a}}_{n}\pars{t}\cos\pars{nx} + \dot{\on{f}}\pars{t} +
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\on{a}_{n}\,n^{2}\pars{t}\cos\pars{nx} =
  \expo{-x}\label{2}\tag{2}
  \end{align}
- Integrate both members of (\ref{2}} over $\ds{x \in \pars{0,\pi}}$:
  $$
  \dot{\on{f}}\pars{t}\pi = -\expo{-\pi} + 1 \implies
  \on{f}\pars{t} = {1 - \expo{-\pi} \over \pi}\,t + c
  $$
  $\ds{c}$ is a *constant*.
- Use (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}):
  \begin{align}
  &\dot{\on{a}}\pars{t} + n^{2}\on{a}\pars{t} =
  {2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{-x}\cos\pars{nx}\dd x =
  {2 \over \pi}\,{1 - \expo{-\pi}\pars{-1}^{n} \over 1 + n^{2}}
  \equiv \varphi_{n}
  \\[5mm] &\
  \totald{\bracks{\expo{n^{2}\,t}\on{a}_{n}\pars{t}}}{t} =
  \varphi_{n}\expo{n^{2}\,t} \implies
  \expo{n^{2}\,t}\on{a}_{n}\pars{t} -
  \on{a}_{n}\pars{0} =
  {\varphi_{n} \over n^{2}}\pars{\expo{n^{2}\,t} - 1}
  \\[5mm] &\
  \on{a}_{n}\pars{t} = \on{a}_{n}\pars{0}\expo{-n^{2}\,t} +
  {\varphi_{n} \over n^{2}}\pars{1 - \expo{-n^{2}\,t}}
  \\[5mm] &\
  \on{u}\pars{x,t} =
  {1 - \expo{-\pi} \over \pi}\,t + c +
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\on{a}_{n}\pars{0}
  \expo{-n^{2}\,t}\cos\pars{nx}
  \\[2mm] + &\
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
  {\varphi_{n} \over n^{2}}\pars{1 - \expo{-n^{2}\,t}}
  \cos\pars{nx}
  \end{align}
- Since $\ds{\on{u}\pars{x,0} = 0}$:
  $$
  0 = c +
  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\on{a}_{n}\pars{0}\cos\pars{nx}
  \implies c = 0\ \mbox{and}\ \on{a}_{n}\pars{0} = 0\ \forall n
  $$
- Finally,
  $$
  \on{u}\pars{x,t} =
  {1 - \expo{-\pi} \over \pi}\,t +
  {2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
  {1 - \expo{-\pi}\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{2}\pars{n^{2} + 1}}\pars{1 - \expo{-n^{2}\,t}}
  \cos\pars{nx}
  $$